# How do I use a tensorflow model to make a single prediction on an image?

Tags: c#, tensorflow, ml.net

I'm just starting out with tensorflow and ml.net. The docs are all over the place. Initially I just want to load a dog-or-cat tensorflow model and then throw a cat image at it and get the prediction out. It's my understanding that the model is already "trained" and so I don't need to stuff any input data into it. I think that I only need to input the image and get the prediction out.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ML;

namespace DogOrCatConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create MLContext
            MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

            using var tf = mlContext.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel("model.pb");
            var inputSchema = tf.GetInputSchema();
            var modelSchema = tf.GetModelSchema();
        
        }
    }
}
```

So far I have used Nuget to pull in a few different libraries:

- Microsoft.ML
- Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics
- Microsoft.ML.TensorFlow
- Microsoft.ML.Vision
- SciSharp.TensorFlow.Redist

I got the model from a Microsoft tutorial where they show how to use a python http function to interact with this model. I have already cut the image down to 256x256 so I am skipping some of the pre-processing steps in the python example. I'm struggling to figure out the api differences between what I am seeing in the python example versus c#.

Answer (score 0):

The above code only loads the Tensorflow model. The code for prediction is not present.
Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/image-classification It uses *.pb file and LoadTensorFlowModel() API.
You need to add score tensorflow model in order to make predictions. The below lines does that.

```cs
.Append(mlContext.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel(_inceptionTensorFlowModel).
    ScoreTensorFlowModel(outputColumnNames: new[] { "softmax2_pre_activation" }, inputColumnNames: new[] { "input" }, addBatchDimensionInput: true))
```